# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable Python

Tags: python, pandas

**I am getting error while executing the Line**  Having a column value where multiple key value pairs are separated by ;.   But when i am trying to execute the below code it gives the Error:

> for ff in f:
>
> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
def strip_optional_fields(f):
    result_list = []
    for ff in f:
        if ff.find(':') >= 0:
            result_list.append(ff.rsplit(':')[-1])
        else:
            result_list.append(ff)  # empty-string
    return pd.Series(result_list)
```

**Later Using the Function to split the column value.**

```
df['Column'].str.split(r';[ ]*').apply(strip_optional_fields)
```

Comment: You can't iterate over a floating point number. Your `df['Column']` contains floating point numbers. `.apply` works on each cell separately, so `f` (the function argument) is a single float.

Comment: Although I see you have `.str.split` there; not sure if you can chain things this way.

Comment: But you are returning a Series from your function; that should probably not happen: the final result would be a Series of Series.

Comment: I would just debug the whole thing to see what's going on: take a small number of rows, and add some print functions in your function to see what is passed into `strip_optional_fields`; that should tell you quickly enough what and how to change things.

Comment: Please provide a sample of source data and the expected result.